# How to keep a bone in place when posing/animating

Tags: animation, constraints, pose-mode

I'm new to animating in Blender and trying to figure out how to keep a bone in place while posing for animation. My character is a monkey swinging vertically across a ledge of a wall. I want to keep the hand completely still, in place, while rotating the rest of the body from the arm. But every time I try, the hand moves along with the rest of the body. Is there some way to pin the hand in place during animation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the task IK was maden for: set an IK chain from the hand to the shoulder (and remember that you can animate the influence of the IK constraint, so you can use normal FK for the others portions of the sequence).

Comment: You were absolutely right and it worked like a charm. With a lot of studying, of course. So very grateful you took the time to respond. Thanks!